# How to set date using variable in bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datepicker

Hi all i am doing one task in that i have to take date form sql DB and date is coming in sql timestemp format and i and trying to assign it in bootstrap datepicker but i am not able to do it so i need some help in it.

below code i have tried but it not fixing my issues.

```
var row = $(e.target).closest('tr');
    var rowData = jQuery.parseJSON(row.attr('data-rowData'));
    var startdate = new Date(rowData.periodfrom).getTime();
    var endDate = new Date(rowData.periodto).getTime();
    var date = new Date(startdate);
    var date2 = date.toString(("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
    var rst = date2.split(" ");
    startDate = rst[2]+"-"+rst[1]+"-"+rst[3];
    date = new Date(endDate);
    date2 = date.toString(("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
    rst = date2.split(" ");
    endDate = rst[2]+"-"+rst[1]+"-"+rst[3];
    $('#devPolicyFromDate').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
    $('#devPolicyToDate').datepicker('setDate', endDate);
```

so please tell me how can i get date form DB and display in Bootstrap Datepicker.

actually when i put static value inplace of startDate its working but it i tried it with variable then it's not coming why ?

Comment: what value you are getting from DB? any example

Comment: "2017-01-29T18:30:00.000Z"  this is the value i m getting form DB and i have converted to 29-Jan-2017 but still its not placing it if i put it static its working fine....@Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem....

include [moments.js](https://momentjs.com/) first....

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker('remove');
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        format: "dd-M-yyyy",
        startDate: new Date(rowData.periodfrom),
        endDate: new Date(rowData.periodto),
        autoclose: true
    });
    $('#devPolicyFromDate').datepicker('update');
        $('#devContractFromDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date(rowData.periodfrom));
        $('#devContractToDate').datepicker('update', new Date(rowData.periodto));
```